# Проблема с MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Почему появляется **исключение** при изменении пароля, ***но пароль в базе данных меняется.***

Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connect = "server=localhost;username=root;database=users;password=;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connect);
    connection.Open();
    string zapros = "SELECT email FROM users.data WHERE email='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
    string updatepassword = "UPDATE `users`.`data` SET `password`='1122334455' WHERE `email`='" + textBox1.Text + "';";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(zapros, connection);
    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(updatepassword, connection);
    try
    {
        string resul = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string updpass = command1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Такого нет!");
    }
}
```

`resul` отвечает за проверку пользователя в базе данных.
`updpass` отвечает за смену пароля, если пользователь присутствует.

Comment: при обработке исключений учитывайте класс выбрасываемого исключения, и конечно же приводите текст ошибки, содержащийся в объекте исключения. В данном случае здесь какой нибудь `ConvertError` при попытке  получить скаляр-ответ от update-запроса

Comment: это я к тому, что `такого нет`, следует заменить на `ex.Message`.

Comment: @teran Прошу прощения, не учел это. Выбрасывает сообщение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

Comment: замените всю строку `string updpass ....` на `command1.ExecuteNonQuery()`, update-запрос ничего вам не вернет.

Comment: @teran Заработало. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь получить результат и выполнить update-запрос с помощью `ExecuteScalar`, но при этом запрос на обновление данных не возвращает ничего. Для вставки, удаления и обновления данных исползуйте методв `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

В случае ошибки выполнения запроса будет выброшено соответствующее исключение класса `MySqlException` (или, возможно, его наследника).
В данном же случае, вы отсутствующий результат пытаетесь привести к строке, используя `toString`, и получаете исключение, в виду отсутствия самого результата. А поскольку отлавливаете вы самый верхний класс исключений `Exception` и не выводите сообщение об ошибке, возникают сложности с отладкой кода.

В дополнение отмечу, что подстановка параметров напрямую в запрос - плохая практика. Используете параметры для передачи значений в запрос.

```
string updatepassword = "UPDATE `users`.`data` SET `password`='1122334455' WHERE `email`= @email;";
MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(updatepassword, connection);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", textBox1.Text);
try {
     command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(MySqlException ex){
    // ошибка работы с БД
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //прочие возможные ошибки
}
```

*зы: когда вы говорите, что выбрасывается исключение, но при этом пароль меняется, это означает единственное - что ошибка возникает уже после выполнения запроса. А после запроса у вас имеется только вызов `.toString`, где наиболее вероятно, что результат запроса `null`*